# Throw after conditional return in constexpr

Tags: c++, gcc, constexpr, throw, conditional-compilation

GCC 7.2 (-std=c++17) doesn't compile this, complaining that `f` is an invalid constexpr due to `throw`:

```
#include <type_traits>                                                                                                                                                                              

template <class T>                                                                                                                                                                                  
constexpr bool f() noexcept {                                                                                                                                                                       
  if (std::is_same<T, int>  ::value) return true;                                                                                                                                                  
  if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) return false;                                                                                                                                                   

  if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) throw "message";                                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                                                   

int main () {                                                                                                                                                                                       
  if constexpr (f<int>()) return 1;                                                                                                                                                               
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

But the control flow should never reach the `throw`.

Is this behavior mandated by the standard or caused by the implementation?

---

**Addendum:**
Clang 5.0 can even compile this, but Gcc 7.2 still complains about `throw`:

```
#include <type_traits>                                                                                                                                                                              

template <class T>                                                                                                                                                                                  
constexpr bool f() noexcept {                                                                                                                                                                       
  if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>  ::value) return true;                                                                                                                                         
  if constexpr (std::is_same<T, float>::value) return false;                                                                                                                                        

  throw "message";                                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                                   

int main () {                                                                                                                                                                                       
  if constexpr (f<int>()) return 1;                                                                                                                                                                 
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if constexpr` instead of plain `if` inside `f`?

Comment: Replacing all `if` with `if constexpr` yields the same compilation error.

Comment: It compiles with clang 5.0

Comment: Updated question to add a Clang test.